# Easy way to transfer a private key to another machine?

Tags: security, ssh

ssh-copy-id makes it easy to transfer a public key to a remote machine.

Is there any equivalent tool for moving a private key?

**update**

Don't do this! (see answer)

Comment: +1 for reminding me to use `ssh-copy-id` to copy a _public_ key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good practice says that you shouldn't copy private keys from one machine to another. When you need access from a new client machine, *create* a new key on that machine, and set up the corresponding public key in your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server.

Doing this allows you to disable access from one client machine at a time, if you need to (suppose a laptop was stolen, for example).

Comment: ah okay, true :)