# Copying SSH private keys

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm using a Macbook Pro and after installing MacPorts my account was messed up and I feel that a reinstall of OS X is necessary. I posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/748268/cant-log-into-account-on-macbook-pro) if you care to read, it's somewhat irrelevant to my question now.

This may be a stupid question, but I have a couple of SSH keys that I use to access some servers. If I back them up to a hard drive, format my computer and reinstall OSX, can I just copy them back over to the newly installed OS X and use them again? Do I have to do anything about file permissions before copying them to the external hard drive? I saw [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/340501/easy-way-to-transfer-a-private-key-to-another-machine) about private keys but it assumes that you have access to both machines. This current OS installation will be wiped and re-done and this is the only computer I SSH from.

I just want to make sure that I'm not going to get locked out of my servers.

Thanks

Comment: Private keys should never be copied! THIS IS A SECURITY RISK. Generate new keys for every new device!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the keys to your new machine via usb drive or network or whatever. The only thing that you need to ensure is that the keys on your new machine (after you copy them over) are only accessible to that user, so you might need to do something like:

```
$ chown youruser:youruser ~/.ssh/id_rsa*
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

You could also run `ssh-add` before logging into the machines that you use these keys for. That will allow you to add additional keys for the same user (on the remote machine). You'll need your (remote) password for that though.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, what's the difference between using this to copy a key and just copy/pasting? Also, am I doing this on my local computer or my server?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. Please see my edited answer.